# Android Studio not start and Intellij Idea is open?

Tags: android-studio

When I try to start Android studio and when i click on Android Studio icon ,after few seconds it start Intellij Idea.
i never install intellij idea and i only install android studio

Comment: Can you share on which operating system you are trying to run android-studio on?

Comment: i use windows 10 , I worked well with android studio Until yesterday

Comment: Do check Shortcut icon by right clicking on it and check the path variable

Answer (score 0):

it solved.
in this path 
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin
2 file was removed 
studio.exe and studio.exe64
after pasting this files android studio opend